# How to create seeding hierarchy in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have problem creating a seeding hierarchy in Laravel, is there way i can achieve hierarchy by just creating a seeding data. I have 3 column [Vehicle,Model,Variant] so each vehicle has different model and variant. I will show you the sample table that I created on excel that I wanted to achieve.

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Here is my seeding function:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Variant;
use App\Vehicle;
use App\VehicleModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CarsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        
            foreach (Vehicle::all() as $vehicle_data) {

               
                foreach (VehicleModel::all() as $vehicle_model_data) {

                    foreach (Variant::all() as $variants_data) {

                        DB::table('cars')->insert([
                            [
                                'make' => $vehicle_data->name,
                                'model_id' => $vehicle_model_data->id,
                                'variant_id' => $variants_data->id,
                                'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                            ]
                        ]);


                    }


                }
               
            }
    }
}
```

Car Model:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'cars';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'make',
        'variant_id',
        'model_id'
    ];

    public function variants() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Variant','id','variant_id');
    }

    public function models() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VehicleModel','id','model_id');
    }
}
```

Variant Model:

```
    class Variant extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'variants';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

Vehicle Model:

```
    class Vehicle extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'vehicles';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

Vehicle Model:

```
    class VehicleModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'vehicle_models';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

Comment: What relations exist between Vehicle, VehicleModel and Variant

Comment: @Donkarnash i haven't yet created any relation to those 3 tables.

Comment: @DavidGrzyb yah i know how to create relationships. my question regarding creating a seed hierarchy

Comment: Won't you require relations between the three in the app? If relations are defined then seeding hierarchy will be easy

Comment: can you please deeply explain to me how gonna do that. I appreciate your help

Comment: Vehicle **hasMany** VehicleModel(s) - vehicle_id as FK on vehicle_models table. VehicleModel **hasMany** Variant(s) - vehicle_model_id as FK on variants table. Then define the relations in respective model classes

Comment: @Donkarnash hi, i already define this to the models. however i got problem on my datas. how to achieve the excel file. i want to insert it to my database. by running the seeds

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following relations

- Vehicle **hasMany** VehicleModel(s)
- VehicleModel **hasMany** Variant(s)

```php
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public function vehicle_models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VehicleModel::class);
    }
}

class VehicleModel extends Model
{
    public function variants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
    }
}
```

Try this

```php
public function run()
{
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('vehicle_models.variants')->get();

    foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
        foreach($vehicle->vehicle_models as $model) {
            foreach($model->variants as $variant){
                Car::create([
                    'make' => $vehicle->name,
                    'model_id' => $model->id,
                    'variant_id' => $variant->id
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what model you are referring two to this 'variant_id' => $variant_id because this is undefine

Comment: Sorry my bad, typo there, have updated the answer

Comment: Sorry i got error on my seeding Call to undefined relationship [vehicle_models] on model [App\Vehicle].

Comment: please take a look on my update question content I add more details. thanks

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vehicle_models.vehicle_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `vehicle_models` where `vehicle_models`.`vehicle_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: You need to have `vehicle_id` column on vehicle_models table and `vehicle_model_id` column on the variants table as foreign keys for the relationships to work.

Comment: let me add the column first

Comment: why i can insert vehicle id on vehicle model? i use this function on vehicle model $vehicles = Vehicle::all();

       

        foreach($vehicles as $vehicles_data) {
            VehicleModel::create([
                'name' => Str::random(5),
                'vehicle_id' => $vehicles_data->id,
                'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226005/discussion-between-donkarnash-and-devge).